# How to write this Store structure?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to figure out the best way for my Redux Store to handle lists. Right now it looks like this:

```
Store = {
    users: [],
    posts: [],
    lists: [],
}
```

My problem with this, is the list array. Essentially it's a store for paginated lists of a specific resource, so for example:

```
lists: [
    {
        id: 'users/43/posts',
        items: [25, 36, 21]
    }
]
```

Since I am using the url as the id, my component that shows a user's list of posts will know exactly which list to display. Now someone has told me that, this is a very very bad idea. And I just want some advice on what could be better. Another approach suggested was this:

```
users: [{
    id: 2,
    posts: [
       {
           url: 'users/2/posts',
           items: [13, 52, 26],
       }
    ]
}]
```

So what I don't understand, how does Redux know where to save this list? Do I have to specify in the action arguments where to save it?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Why is that a bad idea?  It sounds like how REST works, unless I misunderstand the idea...

Comment: @GreenAsJade So my friend is saying that this will get messy really quick and will give me problems when I try to scale. I really like that approach though, any component can access it and very easily too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically, anything works if you make it work! The second approach looks more mature, though. You don't want to use URLs as ID. IDs should be numbers or special sequence of characters+numbers. When your application grows, you'll want to normalize your data i.e. store the IDs in a separate array and transform the array of objects into an object with keys as ID.

Example from Normalizr

```
[{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Some Article',
  author: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dan'
  }
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'Other Article',
  author: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dan'
  }
}]
```

can be normalized to -

```
{
  result: [1, 2],
  entities: {
    articles: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Some Article',
        author: 1
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Other Article',
        author: 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When your application grows, you'll have multiple reducers and sub-reducers. You'll want to slice a specific portion of your state-tree and so on. For that reason someone might have advised you to store your state in a different manner.

But again, anything works if you make it work! Good luck!

Comment: It's important to note that some of these lists do not have an id, because they are dynamically generated (A list of a user's recent post) so that's why I used the url instead, as it is the most identifying string.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Oh okay! So what I did in my project is that I appended my own ID to the objects which did not come with their own IDs. Just loop through the array and add another key named as `id` and give it some integer value.

Comment: How do I tell React components what ID it should look for then?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen That's a broad question. It depends on too many things. I'm sorry.. If you have any specific code snippet, please post it here. I'll try to answer.

Comment: I'm really struggling with this, I do not want to make a bad structure. But I also fail to understand how exactly my components are supposed to communicate with the store. As I have it now, a component just looks through the store with an id and fetches the item it needs, if it doesn't exist, it'll ask for by requesting it from the api.

Comment: Okay! I hope you're still training your brain on how to use redux. Can I suggest you something? Please study these [examples](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples) before you jump into building your project. I did the same. Helped a great deal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121926/discussion-between-sebastian-olsen-and-mihir).